# Construct with the digits

Tags: combinatorics

I have a bit of a problem, How to think and understand this problem.
I came up with a solution.

> How many integers n can you construct with the digits $2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6$
>   such that $ n \lt 5\cdot 10^6$ ?

What I did first was, I wrote it again like is (distinct) $2,4,5,6$

And then I used the rule of product: $2\times4\times5\times6 = 240$

The answer is right, but is this right way to arrive at the answer ?

Comment: How did you get your rule of product? 
Also, I'm not entirely sure this is the right method. Wish someone else better qualified would comment.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure way I did it like this, I just played around and got this result.
But I don`t know way I got it. That is why I put this out, to get an explanation of how I need to think about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy. Since $n < 5 \cdot 10^6$ then the first digit should be $2$ or $4$. Other digits you can put in any order.

1. First digit is $2$. It is easy to see that you can order other digits in $\frac{6!}{2!2!} = 180$ different ways (there are $n!$ different orders but some of them are similar so we have to divide by factorials of the same numbers).
2. First digit is $4$. Then other digits you can order in $\frac{6!}{3!2!} = 60$ different ways.

In total $240$.

Comment: Well explained,Thank you vary much :)